# signalR web application with console examples

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, console-application, signalr

Is there any example of how to use SignalR with a console application ? 
I have read the wiki but i couldn't manage to run my application i'll show you what i did

server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;


namespace SignalRChat.Server
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8083";

            using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>(url)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Startup
    {
         public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
         {
             app.MapHubs();
         }
    }
}
```

Hub Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace SignalRChat.Server
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>SignalR client</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8083/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var myHub = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8083/signalr';
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("Now connected!");
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Could not Connect!");
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm always getting could not connect alert  is there any logic error in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you use the same SignalR version on both server and client - and please use 1.0 or 1.01, not 0.5x.

This sample shows how to do it in self hosting and "it works on my machine"
https://github.com/ChristianWeyer/SignalR-SimpleChat-NOUG

HTH.

Comment: Also, in the SignalR source you can take a look at the Samples, there's a Self Hosted server sample and a console app sample.

Comment: i downloaded your source code in the link you gave but when i try to test it visual studio say that your project version is incompatible so i couldn't test it i have VS 2010 edition

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I setup a cross domain example. Here is what I had to do to fix it.

**On the client-side**

```
$(function () {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8083/signalr';

    // start connection on a different port
    $.connection(url).start().done(function () {
        var someHub = $.connection.someHub;

        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.error(function () {
            console.error('An error occurred with the hub connection.');
        });

        // seems to be a bug in CORs signalR client library that
        // the URL host in the connection object is not passed through to the hub
        $.connection.hub.url = url;

        someHub.client.someFunction = function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        };

        // since you have set the `$.connection.hub.url` this now works
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            console.log('Connection Established.');
        });

    });
});
```

**On the server-side (see [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host) for more detailed server instructions)**

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Don't forget to enable cross domaign
        app.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { 
            EnableCrossDomain = true 
        });
    }
}
```